# My code has to print it one time but doesn't

Tags: java, arrays

Okey I wrote a code to tell me the occurrence of numbers in my array. It does its job but prints it occurrence times. BTW I can't use any of collection, hashmap etc. Only loops.

```
        int[] Bag = new int[0];
        boolean isit = true;

        do{

        String name = scanner.next();  
        int[] NewBag;

        if (name.equals("A")){
        int num = scanner.nextInt();    
        NewBag = new int[Bag.length + 1];
        NewBag[NewBag.length - 1] = num;
        for(int i = 0; i < Bag.length; i++){
        NewBag[i] = Bag[i];}
        Bag = NewBag;
        System.out.println(num + " added to Bag.");}

        else if (name.equals("L")){ 
        for(int m = 0; m < Bag.length; m++)
        {   
            int occurrence = 0;
            for(int n = 0 ; n < Bag.length ; n++)
            {
                if(Bag[m] == Bag[n])
                {
                    occurrence++;
                }
            }
            if(occurrence > 1)
            {
                 System.out.println(Bag[m] + " occurs " + occurrence + " times");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(Bag[m] + " occurs " + occurrence + " time");
            }
}while ( isit == true );
```

For example, if my array is {5,6,6,7};
Output:

```
   5 occurs 1 time
   6 occurs 2 times
   6 occurs 2 times
   7 occurs 1 time
```

It has to write "6 occurs 2 times" one time.
I know the solution is easy to find but i really can't see how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the range of numbers that will exist? Like is there a max number?

Comment: Indent your code, and the logic of your algorithm will become much clearer, which will allow you to identify where the problem is. Indentation is not just for making the code pretty. It's used to understand what the code does.

Comment: Integer numbers, there is no limit.

Comment: ok, what about the max number of numbers in the brackets? Will the user throw a problem with over 100 nums in the brackets?

Comment: maybe the index isnt getting updates when times happens, what happens when you print out n

Comment: start with an array, create a map of element as key and counter as the value, after going through it once, print the values in the resulting map

Comment: Okey I added my array and Its add operation code. I hope it became much clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is going on.

Your array contains: [5, 6, 6, 7]

You are going step by step printing "X occurs Y times" once per array element. Because the array contains two `6` element, you end up printing the output twice. One way to correct this problem is to do this:

```
for (int m = 0; m < Bag.length; m++) {   
    boolean Seen = false;
    for (int n = 0 ; n < m - 1 ; n++) {
        if (Bag[m] == Bag[n]) {
            Seen = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (Seen) {
      continue;
    }

    int occurrence = 0;
    for (int n = 0 ; n < Bag.length ; n++) {
        if (Bag[m] == Bag[n]) {
            occurrence++;
        }
    }

    if (occurrence > 1) {
        System.out.println(Bag[m] + " occurs " + occurrence + " times");
    } else {
        System.out.println(Bag[m] + " occurs " + occurrence + " time");
    }
}
```

The first time around you run into `6` it'll get added into `Seen`. The second time around, it'll already be inside `Seen` so the print statement will be skipped.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't write it on my question. But i can only use loops to solve this and thank you for respond, i know this would help me.

Comment: You should avoid counting the occurrences if the number has already been seen, and not just avoid printing the result. It would make the algorithm more efficient. Moreover, variables in Java start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @HalilM: if you mean that you may not use a Set, then find another way to know if you fave already seen the current number before. This can easily be done with an additional loop to find if the current number is in the array, before the index of the current number.

Comment: @HalilM, I've replaced the `Set` with a boolean. Does this work for you?

Comment: Still the same, sorry. But i understand your point thank you for this.

Comment: But what if the numbers are not in order? Like what if the array was {5, 6, 7, 8, 7}? I get you are just answering the question, but I myself am confused how to viably solve this problem without collections

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper, that's a good point. I don't know the answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work? It skips the number of occurrences.

```
    for(int m = 0; m < Bag.length; m++){   
            int occurrence = 0;
            for(int n = 0 ; n < Bag.length ; n++){
                if(Bag[m] == Bag[n]){
                    occurrence++;
                }
            }
            if(occurrence > 1){
                 System.out.println(Bag[m] + " occurs " + occurrence + " times");
                 m+=occurrence-1;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(Bag[m] + " occurs " + occurrence + " time");
            }
```